# How to have same slf4j log with JDK8 and JDK11 (with String.format inside)?

Tags: java, slf4j, openjdk-11

How to have same slf4j log with JDK8 and JDK11?

**My java Slf4j logger:**

```
log.info("---> {} {}", "When", String.format(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\{\\S+\\}", "{%s}").replace("(\\?)", ""), invocation.getArguments()));
```

My trace in java 8 by JDK8:

```
---> When I update text {bakery.DemoPage-input_text_field} with {Jenkins T5}
```

My trace in java 8 by JDK11:

```
---> When "I update text {bakery.DemoPage-input_text_field} with {Jenkins T5}"
```

**EDIT:**

I try this but same result:

```
String message = MessageFormat.format("---> {0} {1}",
                                      stepAnnotation.annotationType().getSimpleName(),
                                      String.format(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\{\\S+\\}", "{%s}").replace("(\\?)", ""), invocation.getArguments())
                                     );
log.info(message);
```

**EDIT** (if you want a more simple case):

```
log.info("---> {} {}", "When", String.format("I update text {%s} with {%s}", "bakery.DemoPage-input_text_field", "Jenkins T5"));
```

**EDIT** with @M. Deinum proposal **but do not work**

```
log.info("---> {} " + matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\{\\S+\\}", "{}").replace("(\\?)", ""), stepAnnotation.annotationType().getSimpleName(), invocation.getArguments());

---> When "I update text [bakery.DemoPage-input_text_field, Jenkins T5, []] with {}"
```

EDIT: I try other proposal with external replace:

```
String mes = String.format(matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\{\\S+\\}", "{%s}").replace("(\\?)", ""), invocation.getArguments());
log.info("---> {} {}", stepAnnotation.annotationType().getSimpleName(), mes);

---> When "I update text {bakery.DemoPage-input_text_field} with {Jenkins T5}"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Just ditch the string format. Use `log.info("---> When I update text {} with {}", "bakery.DemoPage-input_text_field", "Jenkins T5");`. SLF4J will handle the replacement regardless of the JDK used.

Comment: @Progman, I added a simpler case, but everything was already in the post to reproduce the problem. I hope this will help you reproduce the problem at home.

Comment: @M.Deinum, your proposal but do not work, I edit my post with more elements

Comment: Don't use replacements. Why are you adding that complexity for a simple thing as logging. Log4j already supports replacements. As I stated put the whole message in there and don't do replacement yourself.

Comment: My case is not simple. The original String contain a template: `"I update text {string} with {string}(\\?)"`

Comment: I found a big track. the problem does not come from `slf4j` but from `java.lang.annotation.Annotation.toString()` different in JDK8 and JDK11: `@io.cucumber.java.en.When(timeout=0, value=I update text {string} with {string}(\?))` and `@io.cucumber.java.en.When(timeout=0, value="@io.cucumber.java.en.When(timeout=0, value="I update text {string} with {string}(\?)")`

Comment: here is the continuation of the problem because this one does not come from Slf4j:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651653/how-to-read-valus-of-java-annotation-with-jdk8-and-jdk11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not come from Slf4j but from `stepAnnotation.toString()` different in `JDK8` and `JDK11`)

`openjdk11` and `oraclejdk11` do **not respect** javadoc:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of this annotation.  The details
 * of the representation are implementation-dependent, but the following
 * may be regarded as typical:
 * <pre>
 *   &#064;com.acme.util.Name(first=Alfred, middle=E., last=Neuman)
 * </pre>
 *
 * @return a string representation of this annotation
 */
String toString();
```

**Solution:**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class Sof {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sof.class);

    @When(value = "I update text {string} with {string}(\\?)")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object as[] = { "a", "b" };
        Class c = Sof.class;
        Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
        Method method = null;
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals("main")) {
                method = m;
            }
        }
        Annotation stepAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(When.class);
        Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass = stepAnnotation.annotationType();
        try {
            Method valueMethods = annotationClass.getDeclaredMethod("value");
            if (Modifier.isPublic(valueMethods.getModifiers())) {
                log.info("---> {} " + String.format(valueMethods.invoke(stepAnnotation).toString().replaceAll("\\{\\S+\\}", "{%s}").replace("(\\?)", ""), as),
                        stepAnnotation.annotationType().getSimpleName());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```